# Animation of dots using view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am working on a FragmentActivity which contains a ViewPager. ViewPager is provided three fragments using FragmentPagerAdapter.So i am able to implement swipe screens using viewpager.I can swipe the pages and on clicking next button ,i can move to next page/fragment as well .The following code is working for me :

**1.WelcomeFragmentActivity.java**

```
public class WelcomeFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private List<Fragment> listFragments;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_activity_welcome);

        //FindViewByID
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

        //Initializing the List
        listFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        //initializing the fragments
        WelcomeOneFragment welcomeOneFragment = new WelcomeOneFragment();
        WelcomeTwoFragment welcomeTwoFragment = new WelcomeTwoFragment();
        WelcomeThreeFragment welcomeThreeFragment = new WelcomeThreeFragment();

        //Adding Fragments to List
        listFragments.add(welcomeOneFragment);
        listFragments.add(welcomeTwoFragment);
        listFragments.add(welcomeThreeFragment);

        //initializing PagerAdapterWelcome
        PagerAdapterWelcome pagerAdapterWelcome = new PagerAdapterWelcome(getSupportFragmentManager(), listFragments);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapterWelcome);

        //On clicking next button move to next fragment
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("Current position", String.valueOf(viewPager.getCurrentItem()));
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                // If view pager is displaying the 3rd fragment ,move to WelcomeActivity
                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
                    Log.e("Curent position", String.valueOf(viewPager.getCurrentItem()));
                    startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeFragmentActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class));
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**2.PagerAdapterWelcome.java**

```
public class PagerAdapterWelcome extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> listFragments;


    public PagerAdapterWelcome(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> listFragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.listFragments = listFragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return listFragments.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listFragments.size();
    }
}
```

I want to implement the following screens:

[image: One]

[image: Two]

[image]

These three screens will be displayed one after another after swiping or on clicking next button .Orange color of the dot is telling me on which fragment i am currently working on .Please guide me how can i give animation to these dots ?

**Edited Code**

I have used the RadioGroup to implement the concept.Consider the following code :

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            position = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            Log.e("Position", String.valueOf(position));
            if (position == 0)
                radioGroup.check(R.id.radioBtnOne);
            else if (position == 1) {
                radioGroup.check(R.id.radioBtnTwo);
            } else
                radioGroup.check(R.id.radioBtnThree);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

It is working to some extent but i am not getting the exact color that is mentioned in the design .Please check the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

After adding some styles to radio biutton suggested by Ankit Aggrawal i am getting the following :

[image]

Comment: http://www.androprogrammer.com/2015/06/view-pager-with-circular-indicator.html

Comment: http://nilukad.blogspot.in/2014/01/image-gallary-with-dot-indicater.html

Comment: Check out my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38459310/4631935

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I achieved this by using radiogroup. Position that radio group just above your viewpager using relative layout. Create a radio group with the required number of dots as radio buttons. Do not give any text to the radio buttons.

**EDIT :** Below is the fully working code.

Create your layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBtnOne"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:button="@null"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBtnTwo"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:button="@null"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioBtnThree"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:button="@null"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in the viewpager, put a onPageChangeListener

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                radioGroup.check(radioGroup.getChildAt(position).getId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Following is the selector for radio button button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_button_selected"/>

    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_button_unselected"/>

    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_button_selected"/>

    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_button_unselected"/>

</selector>
```

Now for selected button create this toggle_button_selected_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/your_selection_color" />
</shape>
```

Similarly for unselected button create this toggle_button_unselected_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/grey" />
</shape>
```

Comment: I have used your concept but its not working properly as i am not able to set proper color to radio button .Please Check my edited code .

Comment: Put the code also for radio button selector. Check it now and tell me if you are able to implement it or not

Comment: I have used like this   radioBtnOne.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(textColor)); It is working for me but the color of the boundary of all radio button is also yellow.

Comment: I have never used  radioBtnOne.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(textColor)); so i am not sure whether it will work or not. But check the updated code by me it will surely work. I've successfully used this in 3 apps.

Comment: After adding styles ,i am getting the weired radio button color.Please see the edited code for screenshot

Comment: did you put android:button="@null" in each radio button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103473/discussion-between-deepakr-and-ankit-aggarwal).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Ankit.

Comment: Warning! This solution uses radio buttons, so it will look not like first orange screenshots. It rather looks like gray ones, a circle inside a circle. Don't lose time!

Comment: @CoolMind If you check carefully than the radio buttons have been customized by usin `toggle_button_selected_drawable.xml` and `toggle_button_unselected_drawable.xml`. These two drawables are used to make them look like first orange screenshots not the second ones.

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal, excuse me, man, if I was mistaken. I also tried to apply these XMLs (but with oval shapes) and got non-desired result. But I haven't advanced too much, maybe, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This library may help you....
https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator to add the titles or simple circles for each tab in your ViewPager.

Jake Wharton has supplied a bunch of sample code on [GitHub](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator), you can also refer to the [usage section](http://viewpagerindicator.com/#usage) on the Jake Wharton's site.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewPagerCircleIndicator Library. http://viewpagerindicator.com/