# Android popup with multiple pages

Tags: android

I am currently creating a popup window by this code:

```
View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animation);
LinearLayout linearLayout = popupView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        popupWindow.dismiss();
        popu = false;
    }
});

ImageView imageView = popupView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView.setImageResource(drawables[position]);
popupWindow.showAtLocation(imageView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
popu = true;
```

However, I want the popup to have multiple pages, like here:

[image: picture]

How can I implement a multi-paged popup into my app? can I add a `ViewPager` into my `PopupWindow` or I need to switch to a `Dialog` instead?

Comment: Its hard to manage the popup windows to have functions like these. Yes you should move to `DialogActivity` I think.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use DialogFragment instead.
   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html
2. Inside of it you will need a ViewPager with your multiple pages
3. Add page indicators to make it look similar
   You can use a library or TabLayout for the indicators:
   [How do you create an Android View Pager with a dots indicator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459309/how-do-you-create-an-android-view-pager-with-a-dots-indicator)

Comment: Thanks. I built a dialog fragment and now I am trying to implement the ViewPager inside of it.