# how to increase selected indicator radius or size in CirclePageIndicator in android

Tags: android

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/layout_button"

            android:paddingTop="30dp">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:addOnPageChangeListener="@{landingLoginViewModel.pageChangeListener}"
                app:adapter="@{imageSlideradapter}"
                app:currentItem="@{landingLoginViewModel.currentPage}" />


            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_2x"
                app:centered="true"
                app:fillColor="@color/colorTurquoiseBlue"
                app:pageColor="@color/colorPager"
                app:radius="@{landingLoginViewModel.pagerIndicatorCircle}"
                app:snap="false" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my xml i want to set indicator size bigger when indicator is selected and smaller or half of size of selected when it unselected  but currently both having same size when it selected or unselected please suggest me how to achieve this in android

Comment: **`app:strokeWidth="2dp"`** AND **`app:radius="10dp"`** https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/res/layout/themed_circles.xml

Comment: @NileshRathod thanx let me check its working or no

Comment: @NileshRathod i want selected indicator size double size than unselected indicator will it work as u have give code

Comment: than you need selector for that purpose  @Sudha

Comment: @NileshRathod i tired its not working i dont want storke i want selected indicator double size compare unselected indicator

Comment: check out this ans as per your requirement https://stackoverflow.com/a/38459310/7666442

Comment: tabBackground  this properly is not there in circualr page indicator class  where i will apply this @NileshRathod

Comment: try to use tablayout as mention in that ans don't use `CirclePageIndicator` folow the steps provieded in that and its better to go with tab layout @Sudha

Comment: but i need to do it in com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator cant we do in this ?

Comment: **AFAIK** not possible with `CirclePageIndicator`