# Small balls native component to show current page

Tags: android, android-layout, pagination

Is there an android native component for showing which page are you into?

Example:
[image: Two balls between after and before buttons indicating that you are inside the page one of two]

(You are inside the first of two pages)

Comment: Have u checked this https://stackoverflow.com/q/38459309/7666442