# How can i show the slider on recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebaseui

I am working on an application where I have multiple products and i want to show those products with images and text(like title) on the recyclerview. I want to use image-slider on recyclerview to show my products multiple image with textview. I have successfully retrieve the textview's data from firebase and have shown that on the reyclerview but i dont know how to set the imageslider on the reccyclerview and show images. please guide me.

**i want to show like this**
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38459310/15754377

Answer (score 0):

Image slider is not a built-in component of `RecyclerView`, or Android, for that matter. So in order to show images in that way, you either have to implement everything yourself or use a third-party library. The latter is usually much easier and faster. With some search, I found two relevant libraries:

- https://github.com/smarteist/Android-Image-Slider
- https://github.com/denzcoskun/ImageSlideshow

I also found an article that explains how to use the first library in relistic example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/auto-image-slider-in-android-with-example/

Comment: thank you for your response but i have tried them but the problem is I am confusing on how to set the imageslider like we set and imageview on the recyclerview, how can i set the imageslider on the recyclerview??

Comment: So you would like to include an image slider for every item in the list (`RecyclerView`)?

Comment: How about viewpager for images?

Comment: @user3738870 yes brother..i want to add imageslider for every item in the list..

Comment: If you add your code for the layout of the items in the list, I'll show you an example of how to add the image slider.